# A question from Artin's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $V$ be an abelian group. Prove that if $V$ has structure of $\mathbb{Q}$-module with its given law of composition as addition, then that structure is uniquely determined.

My question is:

1) In my view, the structure is the operation on this type of algebra object, so I just have to determine $rs$ where $r \in R,s \in V$, is unique ? If my understanding is wrong, what is the meaning of STRUCTURE?

2) If (1) is correct, then my solution is to determine $\frac{p}{q}s$ is determined by the addition operation. Am I right?

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: @marwalix You mean my solution is ok?

Comment: The outline of solution is fine

Comment: @marwalix oh I got it, I find the definition of the structure, it works.